# Avoid NullPointerException from user input

Tags: java

I am using JDK 1.7, 
I am checking the code for all conditions of input.
if user does not enter any value in the String then it throws a NullPointerException.
Is there a way to prevent causing NullPointerException even if the user does not enter any value?

i tried try catch block to catch exception

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
class TestClass {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);    
    int i=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println(i);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str = br.readLine();
    try{
        int length=str.length();  //NullPointerException here

        if(length>=1 && length<=15)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Must enter a string");
    }
   }
}
```

sample input-
5
null

Expected Output-
 5
 (Empty string value->  ""  but no exception thrown message)

Comment: NPE is an unchecked exception, so it is bad practice to catch it. Instead just do a simple `null` check

Comment: Also why have both a `Scanner` and a `BufferedReader` to read from `System.in`? Why not remove the `BufferedReader` and just have `String str = s.nextLine()`? (And in reference to your likely future question read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo))

Comment: I think this is an environment issue. I do not get a `NullPointerException` when I compile and run it in JDK 1.7. Please ensure you are running the right class.

Comment: if str is null, calling any method such as .length() will cause a NullPointerException

Answer (score 3):

#### Java 8

```
int length = Optional.ofNullable(str).orElse("").length();
```

#### Java 7

```
int length = str == null ? 0 : str.length();
```

#### Java 7 + Apache Commons

```
int length = StringUtils.length(str);
```

#### Use `Scanner`

Use `Scanner` instead of `BufferedReader`; `scane.nextLine()` returns not `null` string.

---

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println(s.nextInt());

        s.nextLine();

        String str = s.nextLine();

        if (str.length() >= 1 && str.length() <= 15)
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of try/catch you could check if str is not null before you call `str.length()`

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = s.nextLine();
if (str != null && str.length() <= 15) {
   System.out.println(str);
} else {
   System.out.println("Must enter a string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
class TestClass {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);    
    int i=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println(i);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str = br.readLine();
        if(str!=null && str.length() >=1 && str.length()<=15)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Read the documentation - note that BufferedReader.readline can legitimately return null under well-defined circumstances.

2) Write code that can handle the possible null return.